# Extract value from double escaped JSON column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, substring

I have ports_list table with ports column below:

| ports | intended_output |
| --- | --- |
| "[{\"id\":193,\"name\":\"PORT C\"}]" | PORT C |
| "[{\"id\":204,\"name\":\"PORT D\"}]" | PORT D |
| "[{\"id\":45,\"name\":\"PORT I\"},{\"id\":193,\"name\":\"PORT C\"},{\"id\":204,\"name\":\"PORT D\"},{\"id\":271,\"name\":\"PORT G\"}]" | PORT I, PORT C, PORT D, PORT G |

I use this method and somehow managed to get result when there is only single port value in a row unfortunately it is unable to cater for multiple port values in a row:

```
select ports,
REPLACE( substring(ports, CHARINDEX('"name\":\', ports, 1)+10, LEN(ports)-10), 
                        '\"}]"', 
                        ''
                       )
from ports_list
```

| ports | output |
| --- | --- |
| "[{\"id\":193,\"name\":\"PORT C\"}]" | PORT C |
| "[{\"id\":204,\"name\":\"PORT D\"}]" | PORT D |
| "[{\"id\":45,\"name\":\"PORT I\"},{\"id\":193,\"name\":\"PORT C\"},{\"id\":204,\"name\":\"PORT D\"},{\"id\":271,\"name\":\"PORT G\"}]" | PORT I"},{"id":193,"name":"PORT C"},{"id":204,"name":"PORT D"},{"id":271,"name":"PORT G"}]" |

Can someone help me to get the intended output as per the first table?

Comment: What's your RDBMS? Some support JSON

Comment: Write a custom function. What database do you use? What language are you coding in? Add those tags.

Comment: I use Microsoft sql server. Added tags.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: this is my version Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4) (KB4018073) - 11.0.7001.0 (X64)   @Zhorov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those who tried to help.

Posting my solution here if anyone stumbled into similar problem in the future:

```
 select ports = replace(replace(replace(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(ports,'%[\"{}]%',1),'%name:%',5),'%id:%',3),'%[0-9]%',1),'[,',''),',,',','),']','')
    from ports_list
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your `ports` column is a double-escaped JSON, in other words, it contains a JSON-escaped string that represents a JSON object.**

So we just need to get it back into regular JSON to query it. Let's stuff it into a `[]` JSON array, then pass it to `JSON_VALUE`:

```sql
select ports,
    STRING_AGG(j.name, ', ')
from ports_list
outer apply OPENJSON(JSON_VALUE('[' + ports + ']', '$[0]'))
    with (name nvarchar(100) '$.name') as j
group by ports;
```

Comment: i tried using your method and this is what i get 'JSON_VALUE' is not a recognized built-in function name. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Sorry just realized you had multiple values you wanted to aggregate. Also, yeah you should probably upgrade from SQL2012, it was end-of-life'd in 2016!

Comment: unfortunately, upgrading it is beyond my control. it is my company decision

Answer (score 0):

You created a soluntion to resolve only when exists one port.

The function CharIndex is returning the first ocorrency of '"name":' always and the function SUBSTRING always return the string minus the ten last characters.

A form to resolve the problem is creating the user function to return all ocorrency of port.

try create the function below

```
CREATE FUNCTION uf_findPorts
(
    @string nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
          @length INT ,
          @aux INT ,
          @return NVARCHAR(MAX)
           

  
  SET @length = LEN(@string)
  SET @aux = 1
  SET @return = ''


  WHILE(CHARINDEX('"name\":\', @string,@aux) != 0)
  BEGIN 
    SET @return = @return + '  ' + REPLACE( substring(@string,
            CHARINDEX('"name\":\', @string,@aux)+10, 
               6), 
                        '\"}]"', 
                        ''
                       )
    
    SET @string = SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('"name\":\', @string,@aux) + 6,LEN(@string) )
    

  END

  RETURN @return
 

END
GO
```

To Test:

```
select ports,dbo.uf_findPorts(ports)
from ports_list

SELECT dbo.uf_findPorts('[{\"id\":45,\"name\":\"PORT I\"},{\"id\":193,\"name\":\"PORT C\"},{\"id\":204,\"name\":\"PORT D\"},{\"id\":271,\"name\":\"PORT G\"}]')

SELECT dbo.uf_findPorts('"[{\"id\":193,\"name\":\"PORT C\"}]"')
```

**OBS: If exists any error of write you can corret me**

Comment: hi, it is close however my port name is not always 6 characters. For example if my port name is Guangzhou, it will only take first 6 characters "Guangz" using your method

Comment: also when there are multiple values in a row, I want it to appear as "PORT A, PORT B, PORT C" instead of your output PORT A PORT B PORT C

Comment: @rain123  
you can include the comma inside return + ' , ' + REPLACE( substring(string,
            CHARINDEX('"name\":\', string,aux)+10, 
               6), 
                        '\"}]"', 
                        ''
                       )